# JavaScript cookies not saving

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I had a project in my web design class this semester(I'm a newbie at this) and I've been working on a little side work in my free time. I've been trying to work with cookies and JavaScript. We didn't cover cookies very much in my class and I've been searching and searching for an answer to my current problem. Chances are, if you've ever responded to anything on this site about JavaScript and/or HTML, I've read it. As my title says, I'm having a problem where my cookie doesn't seem to save. On first load, the code works fine, then I reload the page and it doesn't recall the cookie value. 
This is my cookie script:

```
var name;  
if(document.cookie)  
{  
var q1=unescape(document.cookie);  
var q2=q1.search("name");  
if(q2!=(-1))  
    {  
        var n=str.split("name=");  
        var n1=n[1];  
        var n2=n1.split(";");  
        var q=n2[0];  
        name=q;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        name=window.prompt("Please enter your name.");  
        document.cookie="name="+escape(name);  
    }  
 }     
else  
{  

name=window.prompt("Please enter your name.");  
    document.cookie="name="+escape(name);  
}
```

This is used once the rest of the page is loaded in:

```
document.writeln(name+"text stuff");
```

In the case of an incorrect value in the cookie, I've created this function that is called on via a button in the HTML:

```
function wrongPerson()  
{  
    document.cookie="name=hooper; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";  
    location.reload();  
}
```

Sorry for such a long post, but I wanted to make sure the community had as much information as possible. Also, sorry about the poor formatting. I wasn't sure how to bring over my entire long thing of code and have the system allow it.

Comment: what browser are you testing it?

Comment: As about formatting, you can normally just copy and paste and the click the "{}" toolbar button...

Comment: In the future: no one cares about your history on this site. State the problem/errors, show some code, and show what you tried.

Comment: You should NOT unescape the cookie before you split it or find the names. Check out setting and removing cookies http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script

Comment: Felipe - I've been testing in Google Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. All are at their newest editions.
Alvaro - thanks. I'll keep that in mind for next time.
epascarello - Sorry about that. I'll be sure to do so next time. Also, thanks for the link.

Comment: My solution was so simple I deserve a slap to the head. In line 8 of my code, I'm splitting something that doesn't exist. Fixed that and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set expire on your cookie script. If you don't put an expire date to your cookie it will recognize as a "one-time cookie". And after a reload or anything, it will disappear.

Set an expire to Wed, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:01 GMT

This is my personal opinion, but I rather use `window.location.href = window.location.href;` instead of `location.reload();`